# Form field value in django template

Tags: python, django

Quick question,

I am able to output the value of a form field using

```
{{ form.field.value }}
```

But I cannot seem to check that value in an if statement.

```
{% if form.field.value == 'whatever' %}
```

Always fails.. any ideas?

The field is a boolean type field.

EDIT - the answer given below works for some fields.. Here is what i'm trying to do;

Form field is a boolen field in a model, using this code in the form;

```
self.fields['information_request'] = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')), widget=forms.RadioSelect, coerce=lambda x: x and (x.lower() != 'false'))
```

The output is correct (eg. True or False) when using {{form.information_request.value}} - but when I use it in an IF statement in the template - it never works..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#if](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#ifequal)

> The `{% if %}` tag evaluates a variable, and if that variable is "true"
>   (i.e. exists, is not empty, and is not a false boolean value) the
>   contents of the block are output:

E.g.:

```
{% if form.field.value %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

To test for falsiness:

```
{% if not form.field.value %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: that seems to work for fields that aren't being altered in anyway in the form...so that answer is kinda correct, please see my edit.

Comment: Please note that this is an old answer. Nowadays you can do: `{% if form.field.value == 'whatever' %}`